# JavaScript: confusion about Promise's resolve callback which resolves another promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I came across this interesting aspect of Promise - I didn't know that the `resolve` function in a promise can accept another promise and it would behave exactly the same (maybe I am wrong here?) as accepting the **value** resolved from another promise

```js
function exp1() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 2000)))
    })
}

function exp2() {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        const foo = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 2000))
        resolve(foo)
    })
}


exp1().then(console.log) // prints out 'foo' but I thought it was going to print out a Promise object 
exp2().then(console.log) // prints out 'foo' as expected
```

I wonder if this behavior is documented somewhere or it is just my understanding with `Promise` plainly wrong

Comment: Promises auto-flatten. `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve('foo'))` is the same as just `Promise.resolve('foo')`

Comment: @JaredSmith I couldn't find it documented. could you give me a link to it?

Comment: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve`

Comment: This is very interesting, I've never seen this before

Comment: The Promise.resolve() method returns a Promise object that is resolved with a given value. If the value is a promise, that promise is returned; [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Comment: https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure